# Writing Appium Nightwatch tests for Cordova React hybrid apps

Tags: cordova, appium, nightwatch.js, saucelabs

I'm not sure how to write a nightwatch Appium test. How do I get the driver object if nightwatch already passes the browser object?

Here's what I have so far:

```
export default module.exports = {
    'Displays error page`': (browser) => 
    browser
    // .url(`${browser.launchUrl}`)
    .pause(10000)
    .waitForElementVisible('.error-page .title')
    .assert.containsText('.error-page .title', 'Oops! Wrong url.')
    .end(),
};
```

I'm running this on SauceLabs and it fails at `.waitForElementVisible('.error-page .title')`

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with xpath:

```
 export default module.exports = {
    'Displays error page`': (browser) => 
    browser
    // .url(`${browser.launchUrl}`)
    .useXpath()
    .pause(10000)
    .waitForElementVisible('.error-page .title') // switch to xpath()
    .assert.containsText('.error-page .title', 'Oops! Wrong url.')
    .end(),
};
```

Nightwatch have well structure of page-object,i tried to use nightwatch and appium last 2 week and it didnt work well together,especially multi-pages mobile app. I think you should find another library to work with Appium, i am looking for it too

Comment: Thanks for your help. Check the answer I posted, it's what I used to run nightwatch + appium tests

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

```
export default module.exports = {
    'Get ABC Title': browser =>
      browser.contexts(function(context) {
        browser.setContext(context['value'][1])
      })
        .waitForElementVisible('.event-cards')
        .assert.containsText('.event-card h2.title', 'ABC')
        .end(),
};
```

Since Cordova wraps the DOM elements.. we need a way to access these elements in order to test them. 
    Calling `browser.contexts` gives you an array ie ['NATIVE', 'WEBVIEW'] of the available contexts. 
    Now all you have to do is set the context of the browser object `browser.setContext(context['value'][1])`.